# How to get static files in javascript?

Tags: django

someone who can help me get the url of static files in javascript.

I have tried this:
I have a variable that has the path of my file and I want to use it as an argument as follows:

```
function(json) {
     if (json.status=='1') {
         var file = "{% static 'path' %}".replace(/'path'/, json.url_file); 
     }
}
```

I have also tried it like this

```
function(json) {
     if (json.status=='1') {
         var file = `{% static '${json.url_file}' %}`; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the path for an existing file?

Comment: If `path` is a JSON variable, you can't. Since `{% static %}` is evaluated at the server side. The client (that runs JavaScript) thus no longer sees `{% static ... %}`.

Comment: @RaoufM yes, i do

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "path" is't a variable

Comment: put `{% load static %}` on top of your HTML.

Comment: You can just do `var file = "{% static 'path' %}";` And that should work just fine

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I was able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function(json) {
     if (json.status=='1') {
         var file = "{% static 'path' %}".replace(/path/, json.url_file); 
     }
}
```